# Why can't I transform the geometry from EPSG:4326 (source CRS) to EPSG:3857 (target CRS - Leaflet's OSM default CRS)?

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, epsg, transform

My problem is I tried transforming from **EPSG:4326** to **WGS84**, and it worked (just swap the axis order), and I also tried transforming from **EPSG:4326** to **EPSG:3875**, and it worked too (the coordinates changed).

However, when I tried transforming from **EPSG:4326** to **EPSG:3857** (default CRS of Leaflet's OSM) to generate an image to display as an *imageOverlay* to the Leaflet's OSM, it did not work.

I have been stuck with this issue for 3 days and still no luck at all.

All I can do is to generate an image which is not matched with the OSM of Leaflet.

Really appreciate if someone can show me the way out of this!

Below is my code:

```
        CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = featureSource.getSchema().getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
        CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857");
        List<SimpleFeature> transformedFeatures = new ArrayList<>();

        try (SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = featureCollection.features()) {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
                Geometry geometry = (Geometry) feature.getAttribute("geom");
                if (targetCRS != null && targetCRS != sourceCRS) {
                    MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS);
                    Geometry transformedGeometry = JTS.transform(geometry, transform);
                    feature.setDefaultGeometry(transformedGeometry);
                }
                transformedFeatures.add(feature);
            }
        }

        SimpleFeatureCollection transformedFeatureCollection = DataUtilities.collection(transformedFeatures);
        try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                "C:\\Users\\Admin\\eclipse-workspace\\leaflet-1\\vite-project\\public\\image.png")) {
            Style style = createStyle();
            ReferencedEnvelope envelope = new ReferencedEnvelope(-180, 180, -85, 85, CRS.decode("EPSG:3857"));
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    imageFromFeatures(transformedFeatureCollection, envelope, style, 1024));
            IOUtils.copy(byteArrayInputStream, output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The error is:

```
    Possible use of "Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator" projection outside its valid area.
    Latitude 117°42.2'N is out of range (±90°).
    Latitude 117°42.2'N is too close to a pole.
```

This is the image generated when I choose the target CRS as **WGS84**:
[image]

Comment: By the error I suppose that `Latitude 117°42.2'N` is supposed to be `Longitude 117°42.2'E`

Comment: what's the source of your data?

Comment: Also, consider using a `ReprojectingFeatureCollection` (https://docs.geotools.org/maintenance/javadocs/org/geotools/data/store/ReprojectingFeatureCollection.html) rather than hand coding your reprojection

Comment: `I tried transforming from EPSG:4326 to WGS84,`  You probably mean to CRS84.  EPSG:4326 is WGS 84 ~ https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks for the link, I will check that out!
Regarding the source of the data, I got it here: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-countries/
And I loaded it into my PostGIS database.

Comment: @nmtoken sorry, with WGS84, I mean this: DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84

Comment: That seems to be used in GeoTools https://docs.geotools.org/maintenance/userguide/library/referencing/crs.html.

Comment: @user30184 yeah I think the error shows "Latitude 117°42.2'N", because the first record's geometry in my PostGIS database is "MULTIPOLYGON(((117.70360790395524..."
The original CRS of my PostGIS's geometry is EPSG:4326, with the axis order of longitude-latitude, instead of latitude-longitude.

Comment: PostGIS stores and shows the coordinates always in longitude-latitude or easting-northing order.

Comment: @user30184 that said, when I try printing out the sourceCRS with:  CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = featureSource.getSchema().getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
System.out.println(sourceCRS);
it says otherwise:
PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
This is northing-easting instead, right?

Comment: Right. The axis order of EPSG:4326 https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html? is latitude-longitude. PostGIS stores the coordinates as lon-lat. Software can do that, it is not denied. PostGIS also prints the coordinates in that order into WKT and WKB. Some say it is wrong with WKT, not as many say it is wrong also with WKB. GeoTools knows the EPSG axis order of 4326 and how PostGIS stores the coordinates so it can flip the coordinates when needed. But traditionally GIS software use always lon-lat and the correct axis order can make implementations to fail. Axis order is a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the [GeoTools FAQ on axis order](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/order.html) - you are making unwarranted assumptions about axis order.

[`DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/fde00fbbec8f703c260641b876c80d2e6e18183f/modules/library/referencing/src/main/java/org/geotools/referencing/crs/DefaultGeographicCRS.java#L91) doesn't actually make any promises about axis order. You should always check with [`CRS.axisOrder()`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/fde00fbbec8f703c260641b876c80d2e6e18183f/modules/library/referencing/src/main/java/org/geotools/referencing/CRS.java#L1784)

Comment: Appreciate your help, Ian.
I will check your links and get back later with good news.

Comment: Thank you, Ian. With the link about axis order, I got the image overlay matched with the OSM. However, the Antartica part is completely missing from the image.

Comment: That's because it's below 85S which is the cut off for epsg:3857

Comment: Now I got it, thanks for your huge help, Ian.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, all I have to do is to add this line of code in my main method:

```
        System.setProperty("org.geotools.referencing.forceXY", "true");
```

Don't even need to transform the CRS.
[image]

However, the Antartica is missing now.